# burg working, but themes aren't

Tags: 14.04, grub2, themes, bootloader, burg

It worked before, but for some reason now I can't change the booting visual anymore.

When I run burg-emu on Terminal, this appears:

[image: BURG lines]

This is exactly how it looks like when I boot the PC. But I can't press F2 or any other key to select a theme.

I tried to change it by opening the Super-Boot-Manager already, still didn't work. Any help?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

`Linux 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 0):

You have to install burg themes

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install burg-themes
```

If you want to setup a custom theme, i followed this tutorial that worked for me: http://develop.alpdesigns.ch/pages/ubuntu/brug-and-theme-configuration.html

Comment: I think themes had been already installed

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I had selected a theme and then renamed the folder of that theme. That's why it didn't work. I renamed it back, now it works fine.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! We prefer answers to be a little bit more detailed here. Could you edit your answer and add some more information?The directory where the themes are stored, for example, or the exact command you used to rename yours?

Comment: Please flesh out your for others.